# How to add a button in a topLevel window?

Tags: python, tkinter

This code is supposed to ask login information from the user. Then when it enters the wrong details, it will do a popup (loginErrorWdw) with a label and a button. The button there will exit the program when pressed.

I'm trying to get the button from loginErrorWdw to appear in that window but it won't. Here's my whole block of code.

```
from tkinter.ttk import *
from tkinter import messagebox
import tkinter as tk
import sys
import os

class Login(Frame):

    def __init__(self,master):
        Frame.__init__(self,master)
        self.grid()
        self.loginWidgets()

    def loginWidgets(self):
        self.userlbl = Label(self, text="Enter username: ")
        self.userlbl.grid()
        self.unEntry = Entry(self)
        self.unEntry.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=W)
        self.pwlbl = Label(self, text="Enter password: ")
        self.pwlbl.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W)
        self.pwEntry = Entry(self, show="*")
        self.pwEntry.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=W)
        self.submitBtn = Button(self, text="LOGIN", command=self.checkLogin) 
        self.submitBtn.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky=W)

    def loginErrorWdw(self):
        err = tk.Toplevel(self)
        err.title("Error")
        l = tk.Label(err, text="Invalid login details! The program will exit.")
        l.pack(side="top", expand=False, padx=20, pady=20)
        btn=tk.Button(err, text="Ok", command=self.exitBtn)
        
    def exitBtn(self):
        os._exit(0)
        
    #change def position
    def mainWdw(self):
        messagebox.showinfo('Main window','Message pop up')
        
    def checkLogin(self):
        user = self.unEntry.get()
        pw = self.pwEntry.get()
        if user == "admin":
            if pw == "lbymf1d":
                self.mainWdw()
            else:
                self.loginErrorWdw()
        else:
            self.loginErrorWdw()
            

# un = admin,  pw = lbymf1d
    
#window = var
window = Tk()
window.title("Login UI")

# window size
window.geometry('700x300')
login = Login(window)

# loop for window
window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot about btn.pack()

This is way without errors:

```
from tkinter.ttk import *
from tkinter import messagebox
import tkinter as tk
import sys
# import os


class Login(Frame):

    def __init__(self, master):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.grid()
        self.loginWidgets()

    def loginWidgets(self):
        self.userlbl = Label(self, text="Enter username: ")
        self.userlbl.grid()
        self.unEntry = Entry(self)
        self.unEntry.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="W")  # sticky must be string
        self.pwlbl = Label(self, text="Enter password: ")
        self.pwlbl.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="W")
        self.pwEntry = Entry(self, show="*")
        self.pwEntry.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky="W")
        self.submitBtn = Button(self, text="LOGIN", command=self.checkLogin)
        self.submitBtn.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky="W")


    def loginErrorWdw(self):
        err = tk.Toplevel(self)
        err.title("Error")
        l = tk.Label(err, text="Invalid login details! The program will exit.")
        l.pack(side="top", expand=False, padx=20, pady=20)
        btn = tk.Button(err, text="Ok", command=self.exitBtn)
        btn.pack()  # Draw it

    def exitBtn(self):
        sys.exit(0)  # Exit

    # change def position
    def mainWdw(self):
        messagebox.showinfo('Main window', 'Message pop up')

    def checkLogin(self):
        user = self.unEntry.get()
        pw = self.pwEntry.get()
        if user == "admin":
            if pw == "lbymf1d":
                self.mainWdw()
            else:
                self.loginErrorWdw()
        else:
            self.loginErrorWdw()


# un = admin,  pw = lbymf1d

# window = var
window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Login UI")

# window size
window.geometry('700x300')
login = Login(window)

# loop for window
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: oh... that was so careless from me. thank you!